# R: Teorema de Bayes

Tags: r, rstudio, vectores

He creado una función para calcular el teorema de Bayes a partir de un vector `probabilidades` que incluya todas las probabilidades implicadas (en el orden apropiado, aunque esto sólo es clave para el numerador de la fórmula):

```
bayes = function(probabilidades)
{
  numerador = probabilidades[1] * probabilidades[2]
  
  producto = c() #Inicio del cálculo de la probabilidad total
  sumandos = c()
  
  for(probabilidad in probabilidades)
  {
    producto = c(producto, probabilidad)
    
    if(length(producto) == 2)
    {
      sumando = prod(producto)
      
      sumandos = c(sumandos, sumando)
      
      producto = c()
    }
  }
  
  denominador = sum(sumandos) #Fin del cálculo de la probabilidad total

  return(numerador/denominador)
}
```

Toda la parte del cálculo del teorema de la probabilidad total (el denominador de la fórmula de Bayes) me parece un mondongo bastante difícil de digerir y me preguntaba por alguna manera de hacer el código más elegante, posiblemente con una función `sapply()`.

Se trataría de multiplicar los elementos del vector dos a dos y devolver la suma de todos esos productos, independientemente del número (que, eso sí, ha de ser par) de probabilidades: `p1 * p2 + p3 * p4 + p5 * p6`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Supongamos que dicho verctor es p

p <- 1:10/10 # Dividimos para emular probabilidades
p

if(length(p)%%2==0){#Probar si la cantidad de valores en p es par
    #Separamos p
    p_impar <- p[seq(1,length(p),2)]
    p_par <- p[seq(2,length(p),2)]
    denominador = sum(p_impar*p_par) #Fin del cálculo de la probabilidad total
}

denominador
```

Comment: Gran solución. Gracias.